# NSDate is not returning correctly

Tags: objective-c

currently I am trying to set a firedate in my app and in my app I have

**Method of getting the set hour and minute to current year**

```
- (NSDate *)timeAsDate {

  NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
  dateComponents.hour = self.hour;
  dateComponents.minute = self.minute;

  NSLog(@"HOUR %ld, MINUTE %ld", (long)dateComponents.hour,    
 (long)dateComponents.minute);
  // Output HOUR 16, MINUTE 1
  return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]   dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
}
```

**Fire date method**

```
  self.notif.fireDate = [self.time timeAsDate];
  NSLog(@"Alarm: %@", [self.time timeAsDate]);

  // Output
  Alarm: 0001-01-01 23:53:58 +0000
```

I am trying to figure out why the timeAsDate is not returning correctly.

Comment: Samo, samo, samo...  You are not specifying the time zone.

Comment: @ElTomato do you mind showing me how to set this up

Comment: More importantly, you aren't specifying the year, month or day! Unless you wanted your notification to fire on Jan 1, of the year of our lord 1. :-)

Comment: @DanielT. Do you mind showing me how?

Comment: @DanielT. See my response below. I think it's because of the timezone? How do I set it to the local timezone?

Answer (score 0):

In swift:

```
func timeAsDate(hour: Int, minute: Int) -> NSDate {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    return calendar.dateBySettingHour(hour, minute: minute, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: .MatchNextTime)!
}

timeAsDate(21, minute: 30) // today at 9:30 pm
timeAsDate(6, minute: 45)  // today at 6:45 am
```

In Objective-C

```
NSDate *timeAsDate(NSInteger hour, NSInteger minute) {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    return [calendar dateBySettingHour:hour minute: minute second: 0 ofDate: [NSDate date] options: NSCalendarOptionsMatchNextTime];
}

timeAsDate(21, 30) // today at 9:30 pm
timeAsDate(6, 45) // today at 6:45 am
```

Comment: I didn't run the Objective-C code though a compiler so you might have to fix a syntax error or two.

Comment: when I pass in `timeAsDate(21,30)` I get `Alarm: 2015-10-07 04:30:00 +0000` As reasons why?

Comment: Because you are in the Eastern Time zone probably.

Comment: The local time zone is already set. NSLog always displays the date in GMT.

Comment: I am actually in PST, but when I tried it. it doesn't fire.

Comment: That's a whole different question.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to **return** a `NSDate`, there is a convenience method for doing so:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
```

This can be called wherever you're wanting to access **Today's** date. I am uncertain as to what your method `timeAsDate`'s purpose is?

You don't want to use `NSDateComponents` or `NSDateFormatter`, unless you're wanting to manipulate the **value** of the dates, or read a specific aspect of the `NSDate` value. This is because an `NSDate` is actually a running **count** of seconds since 1970. This is extremely confusing to most, but [HERE](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2014/04/15/ios-objective-c-working-with-nsdate.aspx) is an awesome `NSDate` shortcut guide.

Your current codes is building a date (see my link) what you'd want to do to access the **current** date is to call the convenience method `[NSDate date]` which returns the Number of Seconds since 1970 - Also known as Epoch or Unix Time Stamp.

For formatting and parsing, checkout [this](http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/10/04/nsdateformatter-and-internet-dates) write up.

Good luck with your concept and I hope this helps you!

#### EDIT - added Image

I am uncertain as to what your "firedate" is, but if you're trying to perform something in the future, a specific length of time after "today".. Then I believe this should help:

[image]

Ignore the reference to the **TimeAfterTime** program. Instead, look at the hypothetical scenario for future date calls! This is just a screen shot from [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=yxwiAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=why%20is%20NSDate%20in%20seconds%20since%201970&source=bl&ots=MYmjoZU7_6&sig=My_QMbB7WSV3au5OTUXSTMf3lSM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFwQ6AEwCWoVChMIvoSP742vyAIVxtceCh05hQdh#v=onepage&q&f=false) development guide book on google.